# Measuring Ping times from Browser, not from the server?

Tags: php, browser, ping

How would I measure a ping time from the users browser to an IP address and not from the server to th IP address. I want to be able to get and show the ping times on a website that shows the ping times from that persons browser to an IP address.

All the code I've seen can ping, but if I'm not mistaken, it shows the time from the server to the IP address and not from the clients browser or PC to the IP address.

I've tried also loading an image in PHP and measuring the time it takes to load (I think!) and this might be an option but I don't know where the time is being measured. On the server or on the browser?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Psedo Ping Test</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php
$link2 = "http://www.is.co.za/Style%20Library/en-is/Themable/Images/ISlogo.jpg";
echo fopenTest($link2)
?>

</body>
</html>

<?php

function fopenTest($link) {

  if(substr($link,0,4)!="http"){ 
    $link = "http://".$link;
  }

  $timestart = microtime();

  $churl = @fopen($link,'r');

  $timeend = microtime();
  $diff = number_format(((substr($timeend,0,9)) + (substr($timeend,-10)) -    (substr($timestart,0,9)) - (substr($timestart,-10))),4);
      $diff = $diff*100;

  if (!$churl) {
    $message="Offline";
  } else {
    $message="Online. Time : ".$diff."ms ";
  }

  fclose($churl); 

return  $message;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take look at [this](http://0x.vc/1r/). It's mainly the same as your PHP example. But done in Javascript.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.